# Synonym for "such as"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, discourse-markers

As in:

> Many factors are to blame for this disaster, **such as**: «bulleted list»

Comment: I want to state that I'm just giving some examples, among many factors.

Comment: Better to exclude "such as," since it doesn't contribute any useful information.

Comment: Note that some style guides advise against using an incomplete sentence before a colon; that is, both what comes before the colon and what comes after should be grammatically independent sentences, which could theoretically stand on their own. They recommend either "many factors are to blame for this disaster: <list>", or "many factors are to blame for this disaster, such as these: <list>". Many others would say it doesn't matter, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few possible options:

> - Many factors are to blame for this disaster, **including[, but not limited to*, the following]:**
> - Many factors are to blame for this disaster, **some of which are:**
> - Many factors are to blame for this disaster. **These include**:
> - Many factors are to blame for this disaster, **e.g.**
>
>   ---
>
> <sup>*but not limited to* may be considered superfluous, as *including* does not indicate a complete list of the factors.</sup>

Comment: "but not limited to" is worth its weight in gold when you are dealing with a group looking for someone to blame.  Sometimes you have to stress that the list isn't complete.

Comment: Consider your audience. Unless you have high confidence that they know that "e.g." can be thought of as "for example" and that "i.e." can be thought of as "in other words," do not use either one. An advanced degree is no assurance that the audience understands this distinction, which seems to cause far more confusion than enlightenment.

Answer (score 11):

", for example:"

", like:"

", including:" *[added in response to your comment]*

or just ":"

Comment: But I want to state that I'm just giving some examples, among many factors.

Comment: @John, all of these words suggest a non-comprehensive list.

Answer (score 3):

For focusing ideas and providing examples, the following discourse markers are suitable alternatives to *such as* and could introduce a list of bullet points.

> Many factors are to blame for this disaster,...

- **as in the case of**
- **as revealed by**
- **as illustrated by**
- **namely**
- **in particular**
- **among others**

Answer (score 0):

What about:

- ***e.g.*** (*exempli gratia*), which means a “free example” in the sense that you're just throwing out an example of what you mean.

The other possibility is:

- ***i.e.***, which is used to restate an idea more
  clearly or offer more information.

Comment: No, *exempli gratia* **does *not* mean “free example”** in Latin; that would be something more like *exemplum gratuitum*. Rather, it is [“From *exemplī*, the **genitive singular** of *exemplum* ("example") + *grātiā*, the **ablative sg.** of grātia ("a favor, the sake"). Literally meaning "for the sake of an example"”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exempli_gratia). This is a common misunderstanding, but wrong it remains. *Causā* works the same way, so *metri causa* is “for the meter’s sake” with *metri* in the **genitive singular** of *metrum*, not the nominative plural which would be *metra*.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know Latin, and I just used an online dictionary. I guess I better be more careful which one I use. That is the trouble with the internet. Common fallacies get reinforced.

Comment: To my mind, _e.g._ works for non-comprehensive lists and _i.e._ for comprehensive ones.

Answer (score 0):

*Many factors are to blame for this disaster, [par exemple](http://books.google.fr/books?id=9Np8nIkHdv8C&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=%22par+exemple+was+beyond%22&source=bl&ots=OeVf0sPKsl&sig=LRgJzHHVqqfCMEHGdpegmU3h4ik&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=D2-CU8zcEYPwOpbxgMAK&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22par%20exemple%20was%20beyond%22&f=false) «bulleted list».*

> [par exemple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/par%20exemple): *(French)* for example

Comment: *Si on avait voulu une phrase étrangère, on aurait précisé cela, tu ne crois pas?* :)

Comment: @tchrist I already heard some native speakers use "par exemple" for "for example." :-)

Comment: I’m sure you have. It’s not so common as *par excellence*, but still.

Answer (score -2):

Some I've used in the past are:

- . . .which include:
- . . .including:
- . . .for example:
- . . .for instance:
- . . .not to mention:
- . . .in an event when: